# DolphinDB: Obtain all chunkId of a partitioned table

Tags: database-partitioning, dolphindb, dfs-replication

When using DolphinDB, I found that chunkId is frequently used as the parameter for many functions. How can I get all chunkId of a partitioned table?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [getChunksMeta](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/g/getChunksMeta.html) or [getTabletsMeta](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/g/getTabletsMeta.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `getTabletsMeta` function returns metadata of specified tablet chunks on the local node. The first column of the result is chunkId. You can also use function `getTabletsMeta` to specify multiple database chunks (with parameter chunkPath) via wildcards.

Create a database “testDB“ partitioned by VALUE, and use getTabletsMeta to obtain chunk information of “pt1“.

```
if(existsDatabase("dfs://testDB")){
dropDatabase("dfs://testDB")
}
db=database("dfs://testDB", VALUE, 1..10)
n=1000000
t=table(rand(1..10, n) as id, rand(100.0, n) as x)
db.createPartitionedTable(t, `pt1, `id).append!(t)
n=2000000
t=table(rand(1..10, n) as id, rand(100.0, n) as x, rand(100, n) as y)
db.createPartitionedTable(t, `pt2, `id).append!(t)
getTabletsMeta("/testDB/%", `pt1, true);
```

Output:
[image]